# HTML, Javascript: button doesn't call function

Tags: javascript, html

I make a button in HTML, and I want it to call function in javascript:

**index.html**

```
<body onLoad="setGameAreaBounds()" onResize="setGameAreaBounds()">
        <div id="scoreLabel">Score: 0 </div>

        <!--div Group-->
        <div>
            <p id="pageTitle">Button Chaser</p>
            <input type="button" id="startButton" onClick="start()" value="Start"/>
        </div>

        <!--The following: gameArea and dot is grouped together-->
        <div id="gameArea">
            <button id="dot" onClick="detectHit()"></button>
        </div>

</body>
```

**buttonChaser.js**

```
function detectHit() {
    //Increase the var score
}

function setGameAreaBounds() {
    //Setting the size of GameBoard/Window
}



function moveDot() {
    //randomly move the button(id: dot) within the GameBoard/window
}

function start() {
    alert("sometext");
        moveDot();
}
```

The code runs fine if I put `moveDot();` function inside `setGameAreaBounds();`

However, it seems like the **button(id: startButton)** never connects to function `start();`

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please post console error .

Comment: I use Firefox>Developer>Web Console. when I click start, it said: `TypeError: start is not a function`  Then below it: `onClick() index.html:1`  Is it enough information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your functions inside your onLoad function and link them back up to the global scope:

```
var score = 0;
var aWidth;
var aHeight;
var timer;

var that = this;

function setGameAreaBounds() {
    //Setting the size of GameBoard/Window

  that.moveDot = function () {
      //randomly move the button(id: dot) within the GameBoard/window
  }  

  that.detectHit = function() {
      //Increase the var score
  }

  that.start = _start; // link desired name to reference to existing function

}

function() _start {
    alert("sometext");
    moveDot();
}
```

Basically, your html functions are accessing functions defined in the global scope after the dom elements were created. So no reference to the function exists when the dom is created. The setGameAreaBounds function gets called **after** the dom is ready - onLoad. JavaScript functions each have their own scope so you need to pass this from the parent using an unique reference. Then you can assign the names you want to the functions.

A better approach would be to define all scripts after
Many programs use an onReady function that waits until the dom is loaded before defining any javascript functions. This is a good approach.

Comment: The question poster will benefit from learning what they did wrong and how this fixes their problem.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewCliatt but many people, including myself, post and answer and spend a few minutes improving it.

Comment: Good point. I'll wait longer next time before suggesting an edit.

Comment: Thank you! I still don't understand why `setGameAreaBoards()` can call `moveDot()` but not `start()`.  Is it because they are called in HTML with `onLoad` and `onResize`?